# XBOX 360 PSU for walkie-talkie chargers

Tags: power-supply

I'm in the process of modifying a 360 power supply to power a 6 unit Motorola radio charger. I've got the +12v and the ground wired to live and ground on an NL-2 connector; and I've jumped the blue PS_ON lead to the +5v rail, as a few other mods have done. When I plug the supply in, I get power for an instant and then it shuts down. Nothing looks/smells fried, so I'm a little stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should state the specifications of the 360 charger as well as the original one you are replacing.  Even based on nameplate ratings compatibility can be a bit tricky as load regulation varies between power supplies.  Sometimes 12VDC means a steady 12V through it's operating range, but aside from voltage ripple, a 12VDC power supply may actually provide 15V at no load and 12V only when at full rated load, resulting in voltage fluctuation for variable loads proportional to their variance.

Comment: 360 charger spec is 12v, 9.6a. Original spec 14v and ~9a.

Comment: Where are you getting this 5V rail from? does the xbox 360 PSU have a 5V rail, or are you deriving it from the 12V rail?

Comment: Further notes: it shows orange light momentarily when plugged in with no connection on the NL-2, Then light turns off. Same when NL2 is connected. If I jump 5v to both RSENSE and PS_ON, light turns momentarily green, with NL-2 unplugged.

Comment: Yes it has a 5v rail.

Comment: You could measure the voltage of a working original and the xbox psu, but it is likely you need to get a psu that matches the original output more closely.  If it drops out as you describe and still works after, you're probably activating the overcurrent protection.

Comment: It drops out even with no load on it though, which is the vexing part, so I'm not sure how it could trigger overcurrenf protection?

Comment: It's not unusual for a PSU to refuse to start up unloaded.  I don't know whether this applies to the XBOX 360 PSU. It certainly does to ATX supplies.